# Assigning values to a divergent integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, divergent-series, riemann-sum, zeta-functions

### Question

If I can assign the series of the zeta function to:
$$ \zeta(-1) \to 1+2+3+\dots$$ 
why can't we assign the integral 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x dx \to 0$$
and it still have some physical significance?

### Background

We know the zeta function at $1$ has a series representation (which is useful to physicists):

$$ \zeta(-1)=1 + 2 + 3 + \dots = \frac{-1}{12}$$

Multiplying both sided by $h^2$

$$ (h + 2h + 3h + \dots)h = \frac{-h^2}{12}$$

Taking limits both sides of $h \to 0$ and using the representation of an integral as a  Riemann sum:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x dx = 0 $$

P.S: I do **not** advocate or endorse $\int_{0}^{\infty} x dx = 0 $ ... Also I have asked a question like this before but was over-zealous with it and deleted it. Hopefully this a better asked version

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that $-\frac1{12}$ is $\zeta(-1)$, **not the sum of the series** $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n$.

Comment: @Did Physicists do use it like that in calculations concerning the Casimir effect. According to what I can get from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Derivation_of_Casimir_effect_assuming_zeta-regularization), that's $\zeta(-3)$, but still the same idea as in the OP's question.

Comment: I think Quantum field theorists in Casimir effect ... However I don't think any type of physicist would use the integral implication of it.

Comment: Your use of Riemann sums are quite invalid. Note that, assuming the integral to exist in the Riemann sense,

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)~dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^bf(x)~dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^{N+b}f\left(\frac kN\right)$$

You claim, on the other hand, that

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)~dx=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^\infty f\left(\frac kN\right)$$

The problem being you can't take $b\to\infty$ before $N\to\infty$. How do you justify the interchange of the limits?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I see ... It didn't occur to me that a change of limits was involved here as well ... I see that clarifies things alot

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: This particular issue is confused by the fact physicists often mean to take an integral of distributions, not of functions. Actually, I think they mean that *most* of the time. This usually amounts to the limits being applied in the opposite order than what you would have when interpreting the notation as being calculus of functions instead of distributions. I haven't tried to think through what this would mean in this specific instance.

Answer (score 4):

As I've noted in several places on this site, a principal reason that (certain!) manipulations of non-convergent series and integrals nevertheless produce useful answers is the "identity principle" in complex analysis, namely, that if $f,g$ are two holomorphic functions on a connected open set $\Omega$ in $\mathbb C$, and if they agree on a set "with an accumulation point" (e.g., a non-empty interval, or a non-empty open subset), then they agree everywhere on $\Omega$. Since many idealized relationships in mathematics and physics and ... are *analytic*, *if* the participants admit analytic continuation in some parameter, and in part of the region various manipulations are legit, then the *conclusion* (and, to a possibly delicate degree, if properly interpreted, the manipulations themselves), are legitimate throughout the region.

But then, no, an integral or infinite sum might not be the *literal* integral or sum, but an *extension* with the same *properties* (if expressible in analytic terms).

But/and this means that instead of just "making sense of" some provocative (not-literally-convergent) expression, we should/must be explicit about what the integral/sum *means*, and how its result is required to interact with other mathematical objects. Not just "assign a number": the "assigment" should/must be consistent with many other things.

Answer (score 3):

Divergent summations arise in physics is when making shortcuts using formal manipulations when they are not not allowed. One can then recover finite and correct results using formal manipulations that are not valid either in that particular case, but this has the effect of correcting the initial problem leading to the divergence. It is easy to find simple examples involving diverging integrals. Suppose we need to evaluate:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)dx$$

This integral converges, but you can evaluate it using the divergent integral evaluations of:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x}dx = -\pi$$

and

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 0$$

This follows from:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{-p}}{1+x}dx = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi p)}$$

and

$$\int_0^1 x^{s}dx + \int_1^\infty x^{t}dx = \frac{1}{1+s} - \frac{1}{1+t}$$

whenever they converge, and you can then analytically continue the integrals when they don't converge. The analytic continuation makes the evaluation of the original converging integral using the divergent integrals rigorously valid, as you can put the parameters $p$, $s$, and $t$ in the original integral and argue that the result is an analytic function of these parameters.

Comment: This is what i ment with my answer. But those parameters you approach a certain function with, will they always give the same result? I've found a lot of example were it does work, but maybe that can be blamed on tunnel vision.

Comment: @Gerben If the analytic continuation argument is valid then it's a rigorous result.

Comment: Sorry for bumping this thread, but I asked a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4323707/analytic-continuation-of-parametric-integral. I don't understand exactly how the argument would go in this particular case as to why the calculation is justified. Can you give me a source? I think you need more than just the identity principle...