# Analytic Continuation of Parametric Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, analytic-continuation

Suppose I have two parametric integrals $F_i$ with $i=1,2$ defined as
$$ F_i(z) := \int_\mathbb{R} dx f_i(x,z)$$
and suppose that $f_i$ are nice enough to ensure that the $F_i$ are holomorphic on some connected open subsets $U_i \subset \mathbb{C}$ (which could be different for each, and perhaps $U_1 \cap U_2=\emptyset$).
Suppose further that each $F_i(z)$ admits a holomorphic continuation $\bar{F}_i(z)$ to some larger common domain $V$, which is also connected. Now consider the parametric integral
$$ F_{1+2}(z) := \int_\mathbb{R} dx (f_1(x,z)+f_2(x,z))$$
and suppose there exists an open subset $U_{1+2} \subset \mathbb{C}$ on which it is holomorphic.

**Question: Do we necessarily have $F_{1+2}(z) = \bar{F}_1(z) + \bar{F}_2(z)$ on $U_{1+2} \cap V$?**

If yes, how to prove such a statement? If no, are there additional assumptions or tweaks that might make this statement true? Thanks in advance.

Edit: the statement as is seems to be wrong, judging by [Example of an analytic continuation for a function in integral form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158986/example-of-an-analytic-continuation-for-a-function-in-integral-form). Can it still be saved somehow by strengthening assumptions? Maybe we can say that the maximal domain on which the parametric integral is holomorphic is connected?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Would you like to explain why?

Comment: You didn't give any meaningful condition on $f$. You can try $f(x,z) = \frac{1}{(x-i)(x-z)}$.

Comment: I'm much less conversant in this material than you are. What constitutes a 'meaningful condition', and how does that impact the statement?